# Server-side Performance Testing of a php Web Application

Tags: php, performance, profiling, jmeter, lint

Before I get marked as dupe of articles like:

```
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635123/what-is-a-good-tool-or-site-to-use-to-performance-test-a-web-page-site][1]
```

Most of the answers on pages like that indicate performance testing of the html, using firebug, YSlow and so on.  Loadrunner is cited, which is good, but what I'd like is a set of tools for performance testing the php itself to identify bottlenecks in the code.

*It's a LAMP setup.*

So, maybe:

- Code coverage testing
- Lint for php?
- Something like valgrind for c, but for php
- any other tool to really hammer the php code and look for flaws or inefficiencies

Currently the best one I've found for it may be JMeter, but I'm only just starting to explore it.

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Not a performance testing tool but a list of code benchmarks - http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: that was *really* interesting - I love small little tweaks like that which make a difference.  Very nice read, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey, I use XDebug and KCachegrind to check out whats going on server side.

http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

http://www.xdebug.org/

They are pretty easy to set up and have been invaluable to me in identifying bottlenecks in my code.

Comment: This is a good way to do it. Also, [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) is a good alternative to KCacheGrind on Windows.