# Cross-platform, cross-browser Javascript performance profiling

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, optimization, profiling

In addition to my [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313224/server-side-performance-testing-of-a-php-web-application) on server-side profiling of a PHP app, an app can have a ton of javascript, being all AJAXy in content.

This begs the question of cross-platform, cross-browser javascript profiling tools - do they exist, what ones do people use, and what benefits are there for each one?

Much appreciated.

Comment: How deep do you want to go?  If you want a full trace, you're talking browser-specific, if you're talking about time tests to see how fast something runs, you have options.

Comment: Full trace - but are there tools that are browser-independent, or at least run on several browsers?  Time performance tests are also useful, but the trace is what I'm really after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://testswarm.com/

Comment: perfect, that's a really nice crowd-sourcing model.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the site still active? I have problems connecting to it

Answer (score 1):

you may do profiling in firebug, dont know about chrome's console though

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HTML 5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

It includes a Javascript profiler that works for IE6/7 as well. Watch the video on further explanation on how to do this. There are lots of other neat stuff in there too related to latest web standards/practices.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is abstracted well, using good cross-browser frameworks and libraries, and avoid using native JavaScript wherever possibile, you should not worry about having tools to help you test across all different browsers.

Comment: I know what you're getting at, but even highly checked NASA code gets re-reviewed, optimised and improved.  Javascript performance in browsers has been improved to a level of ridiculousness in terms of speed as people see new bottlenecks and clever things.  So profiling and optimising is definitely something worth looking at - I've yet to see a project which didn't have room for improvement.